# Angularjs directives access attributes to container elements

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to make a directive which automagically adds labels to input fields, so what I'm trying to achieve is:

```
<!-- angular -->
<label-input label="some label:" id="some-random-id">
  <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
</label-input>
```

and have it convert to:

```
<!-- html -->
<label for="some-random-id">
  some label: <input id="some-random-id" type="text" maxlength="5" />
</label>
```

I've come this far, but I don't get how you're supposed to modify the elements added via transclusion or if you are supposed to even?

```
app.directive('labelInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      id: '@',
      label: '@',
    },
    template: '<label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label><span ng-transclude></span>',
  };
});
```

My main concerns is that I don't want to write the id twice and, preferably, if the id is not passed have it be auto generated, aka:

```
<label-input><input type="text" /></label-input>
```

convert to:

```
<label for="some-random-id-1231231"></label><input type="text" id="some-random-id-1231231" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a link function to your directive within which you can (and are supposed to) modify and / or control your directive's behavior and its DOM representation. For more information visit [the docs on directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_creating-a-directive-that-manipulates-the-dom).

Given the following markup:

```
<body ng-app="myModule">
    <div>
        <label-input label="some label with a given id:" id="some-random-id">
              <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
        </label-input>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label-input label="another label with a random id:">
              <input type="text" maxlength="5" />
        </label-input>
    </div>
</body>
```

A directive that behaves according to your needs could look like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myModule', [])
app.directive('labelInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    transclude: true,
    scope: {
      id: '@',
      label: '@',
    },
    template: '<label for="{{id}}">{{label}}</label><span ng-transclude></span>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.id = attrs.id || 'input-id-'+ new Date().getTime().toString()
        element.find('input').attr('id', scope.id);
    }
  }});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uz76h/

Please note that the id generation is far from bullet-proof.

**Edit: Extended as requested in comment below**

Without transclusion:

```
 app.directive('labelInput', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      id: '@',
      label: '@',
    },
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.id = attrs.id || 'input-id-'+ new Date().getTime().toString()
        element.prepend('<label for="'+scope.id+'">'+scope.label+'</label>');            
        element.find('input').attr('id', scope.id)
    }
  }});
```

Comment: great answer! one more short question though, do you know how I can bypass adding that <span ng-transclude> and just tell angular to append the content after the label tag?

Comment: That's exactly what the `ng-transclude` directive is for. But you could omit the transclude tag by simply prepending the label tag via `angular.element`. Updated my answer.